# Submit task which implements a subinterface of Callable<T> to an ExecutorService

Tags: java, generics

How to submit task which implements a subinterface of `Callable<T>` to an `ExecutorService`?

I have a subinterface of `Callable<T>` defined as:

```
public interface CtiGwTask<T>
    extends Callable {

    ...
}
```

It just defines some static constants but adds no methods.

Then I have the following method where `execService` is a `FixedThreadPool` instance.

```
@Override
public CtiGwTaskResult<Integer> postCtiTask(CtiGwTask<CtiGwTaskResult<Integer>> task) {

    Future<CtiGwTaskResult<Integer>> result =
            execService.submit(task);

    try {
        return result.get();

    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST,
                "Could not complete CTIGwTask", ex);
        return new CtiGwTaskResult<>(
                CtiGwResultConstants.CTIGW_SERVER_SHUTTINGDOWN_ERROR,
                Boolean.FALSE,
                "Cannot complete task: CTIGateway server is shutting down.",
                ex);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this is giving 2 unchecked conversion and 1 unchecked method invocation warnings.

```
...\CtiGwWorkerImpl.java:151: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
            execService.submit(task);
required: Callable<T>
found:    CtiGwTask<CtiGwTaskResult<Integer>>
where T is a type-variable:
  T extends Object declared in method <T>submit(Callable<T>)

...\CtiGwWorkerImpl.java:151: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method submit in interface ExecutorService is applied to given types
            execService.submit(task);
required: Callable<T>
found: CtiGwTask<CtiGwTaskResult<Integer>>
where T is a type-variable:
  T extends Object declared in method <T>submit(Callable<T>)

...\CtiGwWorkerImpl.java:151: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
            execService.submit(task);
required: Future<CtiGwTaskResult<Integer>>
found:    Future
```

If I change the `submit` call to

```
Future<CtiGwTaskResult<Integer>> result =
    execService.submit( (Callable<CtiGwTaskResult<Integer>>) task);
```

Then everything seems to work but now I get an unchecked cast warning.

```
...\src\com\dafquest\ctigw\cucm\CtiGwWorkerImpl.java:151: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
            execService.submit((Callable<CtiGwTaskResult<Integer>>) task);
required: Callable<CtiGwTaskResult<Integer>>
found:    CtiGwTask<CtiGwTaskResult<Integer>>
```

So what I'm I missing? Shouldn't `submit()` apply to an instance of a subclass of Callable?

Comment: If this `Future<CtiGwTaskResult<Integer>> result = execService.submit( (Callable<CtiGwTaskResult<Integer>>) task);` gives you a `cast` warning, why don't try `Future<CtiGwTaskResult<Integer>> result = (Future<CtiGwTaskResult<Integer>>) execService.submit((Callable<CtiGwTaskResult<Integer>>) task);`? You can also post if you tried something like this one.

Comment: Tryed so many things I cannot really remember but I just tested and as I suspected changes nothing. The warning refers to the `(Callable<CtiGwTaskResult<Integer>>) task` cast but once applyed return type and methos invocation are no longer "unchecked".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using the *raw* `Callable` type.

Change:

```
public interface CtiGwTask<T> extends Callable
```

to this:

```
public interface CtiGwTask<T> extends Callable<T>
```

Comment: Non problem :) raw types are evil and should be avoided at all cost.

Comment: Fully agree but I must say I'm really struggling with java's generics syntax :-)